# Incremental interchange format

Tags: xml, json

I need a format to transfer data from program A to program B, and obviously I'd prefer to use a standard format. On the face of it XML would be perfect for this job, or possibly JSON.

The fly in the ointment is that I need the format to be incremental: program A appends data to the file from time to time, then program B slurps the whole lot when it is ready. From what I've read, neither XML nor JSON can do this, because they both require exactly one top-level element in a file.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Clarification:

I need structure of the kind XML provides and CSV doesn't. (Well I could make a mutant variant of CSV that nothing else would be able to read, but that's what I'm trying to avoid.)

A doesn't know when it will be finished (depends on user actions, availability of network connections and other such unpredictable variables), so A can't say "now I will write the last end tag and handover to B" because A might be called again before B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So A *always* needs to write a well-formed file such that B can read it at any time.

If you use XML (and that seems appropriate) you will always have to write a well-formed document (e.g. containing one root node and subnodes within). So you'll have to maintain a DOM object in your process. Depending on memory consumption, that may well be fine.

A can write this whenever an update comes in. The problem here is that writing a file will take a finite amount of time, and you don't want B to read a partially-written file. Some form of signalling that the file is complete will be required here (using temp files as semaphores, renaming etc.)

Answer (score 0):

How about CSV? Easy to write - easy to parse if you know the format and don't need extra metainformation.

Comment: I wouldn't sign the "easy to parse", because most applications have slightly different opinions about what CSV exactly is (think separators and escapes, and escapes of escapes). That is, of course, unless you control both applications and just use "your" CSV format.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was assuming control over both applications. Then it's easy to parse because you dictate the format.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the workflow is as follows:

- Over some period of time, A is building up data to put in a file
- Once that is ready, B consumes the whole thing.

In this case, both XML and JSON are fine, since there's a distinct point where A is working and B doesn't start consuming the file until it is processed (as opposed to something like an always-open stream that continually feeds data).

In something like .NET, you could create an XmlDocument with a root element, and continue to add nodes to it until you are done.